# Function-like macro vs Object-like macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I often get confused whether to use object-like or function-like macros. I have written about both [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros). So if the object-like macro's replacement list can be either literal, or list of literals. Then if we have an expression after the identifier we should use function-like macro right?

```
#define FIRST    1  //object-like
#define INCREASE_A_AND_B()    do{++a;++b;}while(0)  //functuion-like
#define ORED     (FIRST | 5)  //func or object? ORED or ORED()?
```

It would be much appreciated if someone shed some light when to use the one or the other way.

Comment: To make symbols more familiar.

Comment: Please explain the down-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define ORED     (FIRST | 5)
```

Here, `ORED` is an object-like macro, because it was defined without parameter list. Try it:

```
ORED        →   (FIRST | 5)
ORED()      →   (FIRST | 5)()    // Error: Object 5 not callable
```

The use of the macro depends on how it is defined. There's a special rule for macros, though: The opening parenthesis for an argument list to a macro must be given immediately after the macro name. Space characters between the macro name and the parenthesis define an object-like macro:

```
#define MACRO(X)    // function-like macro hat expands to nothing
#define MACRO (X)   // object-like macro that expands to (X)
```

Most compilers let you see what the code after preprocessing, i.e. after macro expansion looks like. `gcc` has the `-E` flag and Microsoft's `cl` has ´/E`.

Comment: Parameter list is not mandatory. You may have function-like macro without parameters.

Comment: An empty parameter list (as in your `INCREASE_A_AND_B`) is also a parameter list. If you use such a macro without parentheses, it will not be expanded. The difference between object-like and function-like is the presence of a parameter list in the macro definition.

Comment: I see now :) Thank you!